# translating from base 10 to base X: an easy method

Tags: binary

I've studied binary-- a number represented by $1$'s and $0$'s. (like $1010_2=10_{10}$) i know you can represent numbers in other bases(base 3, base 16, base 36) I was wondering--is there an easy way to convert between bases? as an example, convert 12045732 to base-37 (i used a random number generator)

Comment: What do you define as "easy"?  There are algorithms to do this, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: what method do you know/use so far for converting?

Comment: You can use online calculators such as [this one from cut-the-knot](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/binary.shtml) which perform common conversions or you can use WolframAlpha to perform all conversions (using [this syntax and replacing the numbers with your own](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert+100011+(base+2)+to+base+16))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert $12045732$ to base $37$:

1. Compute the remainder of $12045732$ divided by $37$.  The remainder is $12$.  This is your ones element.
2. Subtract the remainder of $12$ from $12045732$ and divide by $37$.  The result is $325560$.
3. Go back to $1$. with this new number and continue to get the $37$'s digit, and so on.

In this case, you get $(6)(15)(29)(34)(12)$.  In other words,
$$
12045732=6\cdot 37^4+15\cdot37^3+29\cdot37^2+34\cdot 37+12.
$$